# How to get Redis cache info from requests_cache

Tags: django, redis, python-requests

I'm using requests_cache library with Redis and i want to know how to get info from redis cache. My task is to send info from 3rd party API json in Redis with celery every 5 minutes and get info from redis in my view. How can i do that?

celery.py

```
@app.task
def get_project_budget():
    backend = requests_cache.RedisCache(host=config('REDIS_HOST'), port=config('REDIS_PORT'),
                                        password=config('REDIS_PASSWORD'), ttl_offset=259200)
    session = requests_cache.CachedSession('project_cache', backend=backend, stale_if_error=True,
                                           expire_after=360)

    url = 'http://3rd_party_api.com'

    response = session.get(url)
```

views.py

```
import requests_cache

class ProjectList(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):

     # How can i call Redis cache there by name

    queryset = []

    return queryset
```